# How to make a class act as array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Classes with an Indexer are not an `System.Array`.  But I want to use my implementation like an array. Accessing Extension Methods for example.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```cs
public class MyArray<T> 
{
    private T[] _array;

    public MyArray(int size)
    {
        _array = new T[size];
    }

    public T this[int index] 
    {
        get { return _array[index]; }
        set { _array[index] = value; }
    }
}

public static class ArrayExtensions 
{
    public static void T[] Foo(this T[] array)
    {
        // ..
    }
}

public class ArrayUser
{
    public ArrayUser()
    {
        var a = new MyArray(10);
        a.Foo(); // does not compile, Foo() is unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want your class to have all the extension methods of `System.Array`?

Comment: `AlecGuinness[]`   ...?

Comment: @AustinWBryan exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the extension methods of Arrays, the best you can do is this:

```
public class MyArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, 
                          IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable,
                          IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Those are all the interfaces that `System.Array` implements, so any extension method on those types, will carry over to your type. While that is a good amount, if someone where to do this:

```
public static class ArrayExt
{
    public static void Foo<T>(this T[] array) { ... }
}
```

There is simply no way to get `Foo<>` to work for your class. None. As @TheGeneral as already mentioned, you won't be able to trick the CLR and runtime into thinking your type is an array.

The best you'll get is getting a similar interface by implementing the interfaces that `System.Array` implements, and then implementing these `MSDN` extension methods, as well:

```
AsParellel();
AsQueryable();
Cast<TResult>();
OfType<TResult>();
```

In total, you're looking at around 75 methods you'll need to recreate, and there's still a bunch of other properties you're forgetting, like, `IsSynchronized`. That is to say, if you really want to create something that can do everything an array can do. Just try and be sure this is the best way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

MyArray uses generics, and so your extension method needs to also be using generics.

```
public class MyArray<T>
{
    private T[] _array;

    public MyArray(int size)
    {
        _array = new T[size];
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _array[index]; }
        set { _array[index] = value; }
    }
}

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void Foo<T>(this MyArray<T> myArray)
    {
        // ..
    }
}

public class ArrayUser
{
    public ArrayUser()
    {
        var a = new MyArray<int>(10);
        a.Foo(); // does not compile, Foo() is unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: You only created an extension method for `MyArray`.

Comment: This won't give all the features that arrays have, though. He'd need to reimplement all of the interfaces to give it the same interface as an array.

Answer (score 1):

You cant fool the CLR and runtime into thinking your type is an array. You can only syntactically make it look that way with limitations, also you could probably achieve more `struct` but this will be a pain. Anyway, as you have discovered the extension method isn't going to work. You will have to use the following

```
public static void Foo<T>(this MyArray<T> myArray)
```

If you require otherwise, id perhaps rethink your deigns into what is possible and common and what its intuitively maintainable